# permission denied while doing cleartool setcs in windows

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I have a problem with `"cleartool setcs -stream`" command?

It generates the following error

```
cleartool: Error: Unable to copy "\\nyatc\rrs\view_store\gsm\jpillo\jpillo_atc_1.vws\config_spec" to "\\nyatc\rrs\view_store\gsm\jpillo\jpillo_atc_1.vws\config_spec.bak": Permission denied.
cleartool: Error: Unable to change configuration specification: Permission denied.
```

Note: I changed permission on config_spec but still the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is generally linked to a permission issue.
Check:

- if you have at least access to that view storage shared directory:

  ```
  dir \\nyatc\rrs\view_store\gsm\jpillo\
  ```
- your `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP`.
- your creds:

  ```
  <ClearCaseInstallation>/etc/utils/credmap yourClearCaseServer
  ```
- that you are not part of more than 32 groups (see this [IBM article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC48101))
- that a simple `cleartool edcs` (from within the view) also fails